# leafletjs Geocoding Web Service

Tags: geolocation, geocoding

I would like to know if leafletjs has a Geocoding Web Service to get the coordinates of an address similar to the google one:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeafletJS itself is a library, not web service, so there is no leaflet geocoding service.
But you can use some other alternatives:

- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim
- https://www.mapbox.com/geocoding/
- http://dev.here.com/mapsAPI_geocoder/